# How do I remove the top rack from my dishwasher?

Tags: dishwasher

I cannot work out how to remove the clip from the end of the rail on the top rack of a GE dishwasher. I've tried prying with a screwdriver but I think I'm going to break it.

Model: GLD5660N00SS

[image: clip]

[image: clip]

[image: model]

Comment: Turn it clockwise

Comment: top picture shows that tab 7 is movable ... place the tip of a flatblade screwdriver into the top slot in second picture ... move the screwdriver handle downward to press against tab 7

Comment: Have you checked you need to take the end stop off to remove the drawer? Both my last two dishwashers just unclip with a lever at the back of each side of the rack.

Comment: It appears to me that if you push in that tab, all you're going to do is remove the plastic end-cap from this rail. In our new dishwasher, the racks just lift out. In the old one, they had little clips at the _back_ of the rack to lift them out. Maybe if you give us the full model number of the dishwasher, someone will look up the instructions for you so you will know how to remove the rack. It seems unlikely to me that this is the correct way.

Comment: @FreeMan I added the model number do the question. I used that as a search term before I created this question but didn't have any luck in pinning down that model or any videos that had that type of tab.

Answer (score 3):

push that 7 tab in and pull the end piece out

Comment: I think you means push that 7 tab in and pull the _rack_ out.

Comment: @SteveWellens Pull the white piece out of the metal channel while pressing tab 7 - then the rack is no longer blocked from rolling out.

Comment: @SteveWellens, no, if he pushes that tab in, the end-cap on the rail will come out (with some wiggling). Whether that is the correct way to remove the rack is debatable...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a combination of the other answer and some of the comments together should work:

By grasping the end of the plastic plug and rotating it counterclockwise by 30-45 degrees, the tab marked "7" should pull out of the rectangular hole in the metal rail.

Once the tab is free of the hole, pulling on the plug should allow it to slide free of the rail.

Answer (score 0):

Put a quarter in the slot in the first picture and twist the smaller little tab back to those opening slots and rotate out

Comment: It's not a slot machine.  :-)